# Displaying file JHtml

Tags: html

Can you help please. I am trying to list these outcome  in a vertical order, but it keeps horizontally.

```
document.writeln("Premium ticket cost is " + calcBaseCost("premium", numTickets, baseTicketPrice)); 
document.writeln("Standard ticket cost is " + calcBaseCost("standard", numTickets, baseTicketPrice)); 
document.writeln("Budget ticket cost is " + calcBaseCost("budget", numTickets, baseTicketPrice));
```

Tried `<p> </ p>` but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `<br/>`

so

```
document.writeln("Premium ticket cost is " + calcBaseCost("premium", numTickets, baseTicketPrice) + "<br/>");
```

And do that for all the other ones too.

Although I'd recommend you not use document.writeln and instead write the results into a div

```
<div id='results'></div>
```

then

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "blablabla...";
```

If I have helped please mark my answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the assitance, but I am comfortable with document.writeln.